# QGIS Add Vector Geometry to Polygon query

Tags: qgis, vector, geometry

I have intersected a landcover map with 10km grid squares and then used the vector geometry tool (Add/ Export geometry) to calculate the area of each landcover feature within the grid square. In the resulting attribute table I have four new columns - area, percent, area2 and perimeter. Could someone please tell me what the area2 value represents? I have had a look online but can't find any answers.

[image]

Comment: Do area and area2 differ? Can you provide example data from the attribute table? Did you calculate a field named "area" earlier in your workflow?

Comment: Which tool do u **exactly** mean ?

Comment: Add / Export ? Where is that?

Comment: Thanks for responding! @Erik - Yes, area and area2 are very different and that's what is confusing me. I'm attaching an example from the attribute table, and no, I hadn't calculated an area field prior to this.

Comment: @wingnut - It is in Vector- Geometry Tools- Add geometry attributes.

Comment: @Gio - I only get Area and Perimeter. Maybe the other 2 were already in the original layer.

Comment: And i don't see where the connection with the lancover/grid intersection really is ...